# Making the Input Paramters of web service task dynamic inside SSIS pacakge

Tags: ssis, asmx

I have a call to a web service task inside of a for loop container in a SSIS 2008 package.  I need to pass a date as part of the web service input parameters.  The date is calcluated based on a variable in inside the for loop.  I can calculate it as an expression, but I don't know how to make that expression the input parapmter.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to create a variable that had EvaluateAsExpression set to True.  Then I created my expression [image]

Then I passed the expression as the input parameter
[image]